# Matplotlib heatmap of complex numbes: Modulus and phase as hue and value?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a phase-sensitive spectrogram as done in this publication (Fig. 3 right column, Fig. 4 top panels): https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmr.2014.10.004

For those who cannot access the publication: It is a heatmap of a time-frequency dataset that color codes the data by using the value in an HSV color space to denote the amplitude of a certain frequency at a certain time and the hue to denote the phase of that frequency component.

Every point in such a dataset is a complex number.

What I could do is to transform my data into an `RGB(A)` array to my specifications that are then plotted with `imshow`.

But this seems a bit roundabout (more like the function that I am looking for would do it in the background). Is there a built-in function that I am too blind to have found yet that does just what I want?

Comment: Matplotlib's colormapping is purely one-dimensional. Any other requirement you need to code yourself. Do you need help with that? In that case please provide some example code.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Okay, while that is not what I wanted to hear, it answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have adapted a solution from the [Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_transparency_blend.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-transparency-blend-py) to my problem and wanted to share it here for people who run into the same problem.

The idea is to plot an overlay of a color-coded phase plot with a black alpha-coded modulus plot.

Here is my code (axis labels etc. are missing, but should be easy enough to add):

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def huevalueplot(cmplxarray):
    # Creating the black cover layer

    black = np.full((*cmplxarray.shape, 4), 0.)
    black[:,:,-1] = np.abs(cmplxarray) / np.abs(cmplxarray).max()
    black[:,:,-1] = 1 - black[:,:,-1]

    # Actual plot

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # Plotting phases using 'hsv' colormap (the 'hue' part)
    ax.imshow(np.angle(cmplxarray), cmap='hsv')
    # Plotting the modulus array as the 'value' part
    ax.imshow(black)
    ax.set_axis_off()


# Create complex sample data

minval = -2
maxval = 2
step = 0.01

datareal = np.arange(minval, maxval+step, step)
dataimag = datareal * 1j

cmplxarray = np.zeros((datareal.size, datareal.size), dtype=complex)

for i in range(datareal.size):
    for k in range(datareal.size):
        cmplxarray[i,k] = datareal[i] + dataimag[k]

# Plot
huevalueplot(cmplxarray)
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.